# How to put the output of a function call into quickfix list?

Tags: external-command, quickfix

I have the following function that runs `eslint` project wise:

```
function! EslintProject()
  " Allows using eslint --format compact output with quickfix list
  set errorformat+=%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %trror\ -\ '%*[^']'\ %m
  set errorformat+=%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %tarning\ -\ '%*[^']'\ %m
  " Is lines which don't match the format
  set errorformat+=%-G%.%#

  if executable('yarn')
    !yarn run --silent eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx,.vue --no-color -f compact
  elseif executable('npm')
    !npm run --silent eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx,.vue --no-color -f compact
  else
    echoerr 'No ESLint found'
  endif


  " Restore values
  set errorformat-=%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %trror\ -\ '%*[^']'\ %m
  set errorformat-=%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %tarning\ -\ '%*[^']'\ %m
  set errorformat-=%-G%.%#
endfunction
```

I'm trying to define a command for that:

```
command! -bar EslintProject call EslintProject() | cexpr | cw | redraw!
```

However, the quickfix list is not populated.

Is there a way of populating the quickfix list from a function call which executes external commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
com -bar EslintProject call EslintProject()

fu EslintProject() abort
  if executable('yarn')
    let cmd = 'yarn run --silent eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx,.vue --no-color -f compact'
  elseif executable('npm')
    let cmd = 'npm run --silent eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx,.vue --no-color -f compact'
  else
    echoerr 'No ESLint found'
  endif

  let efm = &efm
  let efm ..= ',%f: line %l\, col %c\, %trror - ''%*[^'']'' %m'
  let efm ..= ',%f: line %l\, col %c\, %tarning - ''%*[^'']'' %m'
  let efm ..= ',%-G%.%#'

  sil let qfl = getqflist({'lines': systemlist(cmd), 'efm': efm})
  call setqflist(get(qfl, 'items', []))
  cw
endfu
```

If the error format doesn't work as expected, visit [this site](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/) to build a better one.

---

You can get a quickfix list resulting from the parsing of the output of an arbitrary shell command, with an arbitrary error format, with this expression:

```
getqflist({'lines': systemlist('my shell command'), 'efm': 'my error format'})
```

As an example, this snippet should populate a valid quickfix list with all the files in `/etc` whose name end with `.conf`:

```
let qfl = getqflist({'lines': systemlist('find /etc/ -name "*.conf"'), 'efm': '%f'})
call setqflist(get(qfl, 'items', []))
cw
```

---

For more info, see:

```
:h getqflist()
:h setqflist()
:h getqflist-examples
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot @user938271... Works if I set `let efm = '%f: line %l\, col %c\, %trror - ''%*[^'']'' %m'` instead of appending the pattern. If I copy and paste exacltly as your example, it complains about having too many `%f` arguments. I guess that's because my `efm` is not empty.

Comment: I think that's because I forgot a  comma; I updated the code.

Comment: Yeah, but since this `efm` is only used inside the function and the function only uses eslint format, I see no reason to mix it with the global `efm`. But it works as well... Thank you very much. I've been a Vimer for almost 8 years and only now I'm trying to dive into vimscript. It's harder than I though :'D